# How to get the WebBrowser control to close jpg file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a .Net 4 (VS 2010) WinForms application where I am using the WebBrowser control to view .jpg files on the local hard drive. I open the file by calling:

```
this.webBrowser1.Navigate("c:\Folder1\myfile.jpg");
```

I then have a button for the user to click to move the file to a different folder after viewing it.

```
File.Move("c:\Folder1\myfile.jpg","c:\Folder2\myfile.jpg");
```

This throws an IOException because the WebBrowser control still has the file open.

I have tried calling Navigate("about:blank"), I have tried Disposing the WebBrowser control, etc, and nothing works. What is a good way to get the WebBrowser control to close the jpg file?

If no other solution is found, I will be forced to copy the jpg to a temporary folder and use it for viewing, so that I can move the original around as needed.

Comment: I created a test project and did exactly as you said  and it worked. Maybe there is something else?

Comment: One slight difference would be that in my production code I am loading the file from a mapped network drive (and moving it to another folder on that same drive). I wouldn't think that would cause any difference in behavior though.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found a bug in another section of my code.  I have this method that I call in the Navigated and Resize events of the WebBrowser control, to zoom the control so that the image fits to the width of the control.

```
private void SetBrowserZoom()
    {
        if (CurrentSelectedFilePath.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg"))
        {
            var bitMap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(CurrentSelectedFilePath);
            decimal imageWidth = bitMap.Width;
            decimal browserWidth = WebBrowser.Width - 40;
            decimal zoomFactor = decimal.Round((browserWidth / imageWidth) * 100, 0);
            WebBrowser.Document.Images[0].Style = "zoom: " + zoomFactor.ToString() + "%";
            bitMap.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I was not calling Dispose() on the bitmap, and that is what was keeping the file open. After I added the call to bitMap.Dispose() the issue went away.

Thanks to those who took time to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you aren't tied to the web browser control then you could use a picturebox instead:</strike>

Drop a PictureBox on your form and name it `PictureView`

```
PictureView.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("path to the image")
```

If you MUST use a webbrowser control then you might consider making a copy of the image to a temp location and point the browser to the temp copy.

Comment: I am tied to the WebBrowser control. I want to also use it to view pdf files (it quite nicely loads Adobe Reader right up within the WebBrowser).

Comment: well then theres the temp location deal.  there are other ways to deal with it if a temp location doesnt work for you.